# i've got tired make border-radius with 75% of height

Tags: html, css

I've got tired trying make border like in the design with CSS, anyone has any idea how to do it.

i try :

- border-image
- after & before (pseudo-elements)
- i try many tricks but nothing.

```
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-left-style: inset;
  border-right-style: outset;
```

[here the image border design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHX6z.jpg)

is this possible !?

thanks for interesting.

Comment: I'm not sure CSS has this capability. You may have to use an SVG or somehow use a background image.

Comment: @RiverTam i will try to find something with it as i hope because i don't an expert with SVG, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly, see if this approach helps you in solving your problem

```css
        .search-box {
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            border-left-color: red;
            border-right-color: red;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-size: 18px;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 40px;
            background-image: url('https://img1.gratispng.com/20180516/w/kisspng-electric-light-copyright-free-incandescent-light-b-5afbadc7aee409.3907345415264434637164.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: auto 80%;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using pseudo-elements:

```css
:root {
  --shift: 0.8em;
  --border: 0.3em;
  --padding: 1em 1.5em;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  /* Prevent red dots from overflowing */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Create pill-like shape */
  border-radius: 100em;
  /* Border thickness */
  padding: var(--border);
  background: #ddd;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100em;
  padding: var(--padding);
  /* This overlays the red dots */
  z-index: 100;
}

/* Red dots */
div::before, div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: #f00;
}

div::before {
  right: calc(100% - var(--shift));
}

div::after {
  left: calc(100% - var(--shift));
}

/* Demo only */

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3em 0;
}

input:active, input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: this is a good trick with pseudo-elements i believe it can use too with the new idea in my brain, thanks for your effort man.